# How to create an AngularJS custom email directive which has @something.com as placeholder and appends it at the end of user's entry?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, email-validation

I'm looking for a way to set-up a custom email input directive that already has "something.com" both as placeholder and as part of the input. Then it would look at user's entry until user types '@'; then append whatever user's typed in plus the placeholder. It would not let users to type '@' since this is going to be where we won't let them type more characters.

This is for a use case where all the email addresses end with "something.com", so we want users not to type "something.com".

My directive starting point:

```
angular.module('myDirectives').directive('customEmail', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A'
    , require: 'ngModel'
    , scope: {
    }
    , link: function (scope, ele, attrs, ngModel) {

        var emailArray = ["something.com"];
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value){
            emailArray.unshift(value);
            console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + emailArray);
            //return value + endingPart;
        });
    }
};
```

})

My html code:

```
<div>
     <input custom-email type="email" class="col-sm-9" id="execEmail" ng-model="options.execEmail" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@something.com$/" autofocus/>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Add the @something.com outside the input box. Then, restrict the input box to parse the text on change, so it removes any "@" symbol on change.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since I got it working, I'm going to post my code so it could be potentially referenced in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myDirectives').directive('customEmail', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel'
    , scope: {
    }
    , link: function (scope, ele, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        scope.atSignPosition = 0;
        scope.input = document.getElementById('emailInput');
        var emailSuffix = '@something.com';

        scope.appendEmail = function (inputValue) {
            if (!inputValue) {
                return;
            }

            var newEmail = inputValue + emailSuffix;

            if (inputValue.indexOf('@') > -1) {
                return inputValue;
            }

            scope.atSignPosition = newEmail.indexOf('@');
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(newEmail);
            modelCtrl.$render();
            scope.setCaretPosition();

            return newEmail;
        }

        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(scope.appendEmail);
        scope.appendEmail(scope[attrs.ngModel]);

        scope.setCaretPosition = function () {
            if (scope.input != null && scope.input.createTextRange) {
                var range = scope.input.createTextRange();
                range.collapse(true);
                range.move('character', scope.atSignPosition);
                range.select();
            }
            else if (scope.input != null && scope.input.setSelectionRange) {
                scope.input.focus();
                scope.input.setSelectionRange(scope.atSignPosition, scope.atSignPosition);
            }

        }

    }
};
```

})

and template:

```
<div>
 <input custom-email type="text" class="col-sm-9" id="emailInput" ng-model="options.email" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@something.com$/" autofocus/>
```